# Using Python to enumerate transitive relations on a set

Tags: combinatorics

For a long time, I have been trying to enumerate transitive relations on an n-element set containing only three ordered pairs. Recently, I started learning Python. I feel that Python would help in this regard. But how so? I am stuck.

Comment: A suggestion: clearly write out what a "transitive relation on an $n$-element set" is, and post this on StackOverflow.

Comment: I shall do so. But I am hopeful to get some response here too.

Comment: If all you are interested in is counting the number, you should be able with some tedious effort break into cases: 3 loops, 2 loops with edge connecting them, 2 loops with an edge entering or leaving one, etc... or the biggest and perhaps most important case, three unconnected edges where no first element in a pair is equal to any of the pairs' second elements.  Each specific case can be counted with standard elementary techniques.

Comment: What do you mean by "containing only three ordered pairs"? The number of all transitive relations on an $n$-element set will be enormous for large $n$, so unless year condition eliminates a lot of the relations, then a  program to list all the relations will have an enormous number of outputs.

Comment: @Rob Arthan, I mean I am interested in finding out how many 3-element subsets of the Cartesian product are transitive.